# Webpack + Typescript : Getting Module Parse failed - why?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm building a knockoutJs project using Typescript and Webpack, and I'm hitting a very weird issue.

The module that webpack is failing on is this:

```
import esPlayerVM from "./components/es-player";
import esPlayerTemplate from "./components/es-player.tmpl.html";
import fsButtonVm from "./components/fullscreen-button";
import fsButtonHtml from "./components/fullscreen-button.tmpl.html";


export default class Registrator {

    static Register() {
        var koComp = (elName: string, vm: any, html: string) => {
            ko.components.register(elName, { viewModel: vm, template: html });
        }

        koComp('es-player', esPlayerVM, esPlayerTemplate);
        koComp('fullscreen-button', fsButtonVm, fsButtonHtml);
        //ko.components.register('es-player', { viewModel: esPlayerVM, template: esPlayerTemplate });
        //this.RegisterComponent('fullscreen-button', fsButtonVm, fsButtonHtml);
    }
}
```

Webpack outputs this:

```
ERROR in ./ComponentRegistration.ts
Module parse failed: C:\Users\Marlon\Documents\Projects\eps-ko\src\ComponentRegistration.ts Unexpected token (10:28)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
|     static Register() {
|         var koComp = (elName: string, vm: any, html: string) => {
|             ko.components.register(elName, { viewModel: vm, template: html });
|         }
 @ ./Main.ts 16:0-50
```

If I remove the `koComp` varable, and directly register the component in the `Register` method, webpack is happy. Originally I had a private static function as you can see from the bottom comment, but webpack had the same problem with that.

I have googled, and others are getting this when typescript is outputting `es2016` code, so they have to pass it through babel, however I am targetting es5 so I would expect mine to be fine? I am not using any react stuff like .tsx files either.

I've used both `ts-loader` and `awesome-typescript-loader`, both have the same error.

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "module": "es2015",
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "importHelpers": true
    }
}
```

Originally I hade `modules` set to `commonjs`, but when trying `ts-loader` I followed their example.

Here is my `webpack.config`:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const { CheckerPlugin } = require('awesome-typescript-loader')

// Create multiple instances
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('es-player.bundle.css');

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
  entry: {
    app: './Main.ts',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'es-player.bundle.js',
  },
  //devtool: "cheap-eval-source-map",
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx']
  },    
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      }
    ],
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: extractCSS.extract([ 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader' ])
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/i,
        use: extractCSS.extract([ 'css-loader', 'less-loader', 'postcss-loader' ])
      },
      {
        test: /\.tmpl.html?$/,
        use: 'raw-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    extractCSS
    //new CheckerPlugin()
  ],
};
```

Versions:

```
Typescript: 2.2.2
Webpack: 2.3.3
awesome-typescript-loader: 3.1.2
ts-loader: 2.0.3
```

I could just register them directly, but I am wondering what is happening that is causing this error.

*edit*

After digging and deleting code, it seems webpack is failing if any exported module has typed parameters on any method etc. This is really wierd as I thought webpack was working with the transpiled javascript generated from the loaders? This infers it is trying to work with the raw .ts files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL:DR The use of both `loaders` and `rules` sections is not supported by WebPack - must use one or the other.**

After hours of debugging, it was due to having the typescript loader defined in the `loaders` section of the `webpack.config.js` file. Moving it into the `rules` section fixed the issue.

Amended `webpack.config.js` file looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const { CheckerPlugin } = require('awesome-typescript-loader')

const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('es-player.bundle.css');

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
  entry: {
    app: './Main.ts',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'es-player.bundle.js',
  },
  //devtool: "cheap-eval-source-map",
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx']
  },    
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: extractCSS.extract([ 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader' ])
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/i,
        use: extractCSS.extract([ 'css-loader', 'less-loader', 'postcss-loader' ])
      },
      {
        test: /\.tmpl.html?$/,
        use: 'raw-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    extractCSS,
    new CheckerPlugin()
  ],
};
```

Both `ts-loader` and the `at-loader` state to define them in the `loaders` sections on their respective github pages. But the Webpack 2 [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/webpack-and-typescript/) state to put them in the `rules` section. Very confusing to say the least.